# Is "metonymically imply" redundant?

Tags: phrases

Is "metonymically imply" redundant in this sentence:

> The poet shows this distance from the divine by identifying the stomach and womb as definitive traits of the human condition; these organs **metonymically imply** that human beings are susceptible to both deception and physical desire.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Let's say for argument's sake that the phrase is redundant. How would you reword the passage to retain the sense of the original?

Comment: Are you asking if both bolded words can be removed or one of them?

Comment: No, a metonym is the renaming of something by a part or characteristic of that thing.  For instance to call a helper "my right hand."  Where *hand* renames the person who's helping.